# items are gray even tho i pushed texture soild and inverts my other items

Tags: objects, blend-files, world

my objects are gray even tho they texture solid then my guns and car goes gray when I put my characters solid

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have a few guesses, but this would be a lot easier if you uploaded your blend file. It may be that the objects shader doesn't have the right texture selected to show up in texture solid mode.

Comment: please upload blend file